# nbconvert failed: No suitable chromium executable found on the system. Please use '--allow-chromium-download' to allow downloading one

Tags: jupyter-notebook, chromium, nbconvert, pyppeteer

Getting error as "nbconvert failed: No suitable chromium executable found on the system. Please use '--allow-chromium-download' to allow downloading one." while trying to download jupyter notebook file (.ipynb) as a PDF file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Install and execute `pyppeteer-install` in your command prompt as below:
2. `pyppeteer-install`

   > [INFO] Starting Chromium download.
   >
   > 100%|█| 137M/137M
   >
   > [INFO] Beginning extraction
   >
   > [INFO] Chromium extracted to: C:\Users\AppData\Local\pyppeteer\pyppeteer\local-chromium\588429
3. Now the selected `ipynb` file should get extracted as a PDF while downloading with the "PDF via HTML (.pdf)" option.